# VBA Macros: Exporting Visio Shape Report into New Excel File, then Creating a Pivot Table

Tags: excel, vba, visio

So basically, I have a Visio file that has lots of shapes and data.  I'm trying to create a shape report into a new excel file, and then have the excel file turn the exported data into a pivot table programmatically.

I have a macro running in Visio that generates the excel file with data in normal table form already.  I want to be able to run a macro in Visio that activates the excel window of exported data and runs a macro to make it into a pivot table.  However, any excel macro code I put into my visio macro modules is unrecognized (e.g. "Range"), presumably because they're not words recognized by Visio.

My question is this:  How do I run a macro that alters an Excel file FROM a Visio module?

I know how to call a macro IN an Excel file from Visio (Excel.run "ModuleNAME"), but that would require the macro to already be in Excel.  Since I'm creating new Excel files when I get shape reports, these files don't have any macros in them.

An alternative solution would be if I was able to export shape data report from Visio as a new sheet to an EXISTING Excel file that already contained the macro, but I'm not sure how to do this either... (export shape reports from Visio to existing Excel file)

My Code to Generate Excel Report:

```
Sub Excel2()
Visio.Application.Addons("VisRpt").Run     
("/rptDefName=ReportDefinition_2.vrd/rptOutput=EXCEL")
End Sub
```

I would like to run this macro after running Excel2()

```
Sub NewMacro()
AppActivate "Microsoft Excel"
Dim AppExcel As Excel.Application
Set AppExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

'Do all sorts of fancy stuff with making pivot tables
'Do all sorts of fancy stuff with making pivot tables
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to add a reference to Excel in your Visio VB project. Then you should be able to work with Excel directly from your Visio code.

Comment: @ays0110: Further to what Tim suggested, it would also help if you can show us the code that you are using to export to Excel ;)

Comment: @ays0110: Based on your other comment, what would happen if there are multiple excel files open? How do you intend to bind with the right excel file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use the Get/CreateObject function to use an Excel application instance from Visio.

Have a look at this article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg251785.aspx

You might also find this useful:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/309603

...it describes the opposite direction (ie controling Visio from another app), but in your case you'd do something like:

```
Dim AppExcel As Excel.Application

   On Error Resume Next

   Set AppExcel = GetObject(, "excel.application")

   If AppExcel Is Nothing Then
      Set AppExcel = CreateObject("excel.application")
   End If
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you-- this is helpful!  But to further expound upon my question, I'm specifically looking for some way of using VBA to access a newly created file that is not saved.  The createObject function creates a new excel file, whereas the GetObject function accesses a file that is already saved at some path.  I have a newly created (unsaved) excel file open at the same time as my Visio.  How do I direct VBA to "switch windows" and work with the Excel instead?

Comment: @ays0110 GetObject (as above) will return the open instance of Excel application (if it exists).  You can then iterate through the Workbooks collection to make sure you've got the one you're after.  If you're having trouble getting hold of it you might have to add a DoEvents to ensure that the report has been generated.